# Failures while setting up mutt on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, mutt

Following is my shell script which I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 as pipeline task.

```
echo "line1"
sudo apt-get update
echo "line2"
sudo apt install snapd
echo "line3"
#sudo apt-get install -y xpdf
sudo snap install okular
echo "line4"
sudo apt install mailutils
echo "line5"
sudo apt install mutt
```

However, I am getting failures and mailutils as well as mutt is not getting installed. I am not able to find what exactly is wrong.

Can someone help.

Following is the log.

```
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0615819Z ##[section]Starting: Install mail agents
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620141Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620279Z Task         : Bash
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620345Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620458Z Version      : 3.214.0
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620527Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620605Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-06-12T10:03:49.0620741Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-12T10:03:49.2001702Z Generating script.
2023-06-12T10:03:49.2022486Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-12T10:03:49.2035671Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/30cb8767-1ec0-4c8d-904d-bf75d1b0dcb8.sh
2023-06-12T10:03:49.2086880Z line1
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3512316Z Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3513520Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3514187Z Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3525074Z Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3629348Z Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
2023-06-12T10:03:49.3835445Z Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [3611 B]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.9524150Z Get:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2613 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.9818079Z Get:8 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [440 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.9825266Z Get:9 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16.8 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:49.9916353Z Get:10 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1937 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.0046726Z Get:11 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [273 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.0155209Z Get:12 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1070 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.0279798Z Get:13 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [255 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.0287027Z Get:14 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [25.0 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.1013907Z Get:15 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages [45.7 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.1034309Z Get:16 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1420 B]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.1495430Z Get:17 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [25.0 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.1506617Z Get:18 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [880 B]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2194139Z Get:19 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [2232 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2387760Z Get:20 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [358 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2433105Z Get:21 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [13.0 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2457368Z Get:22 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1833 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2666230Z Get:23 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [256 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2675256Z Get:24 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [844 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2814081Z Get:25 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [174 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.2822713Z Get:26 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [18.5 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.4612538Z Get:27 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main arm64 Packages [41.0 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.4632779Z Get:28 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main armhf Packages [14.6 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:50.4655137Z Get:29 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [202 kB]
2023-06-12T10:03:56.8883268Z Fetched 13.0 MB in 3s (4990 kB/s)
2023-06-12T10:03:58.0626193Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-12T10:03:58.0844624Z line2
2023-06-12T10:03:58.0950202Z 
2023-06-12T10:03:58.0951019Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-12T10:03:58.0951268Z 
2023-06-12T10:03:58.1490184Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-12T10:03:58.3585009Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-12T10:03:58.3600185Z Reading state information...
2023-06-12T10:03:58.5574824Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-12T10:03:58.5575936Z   zenity | kdialog
2023-06-12T10:03:58.6190432Z The following packages will be upgraded:
2023-06-12T10:03:58.6191325Z   snapd
2023-06-12T10:03:58.6629495Z 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
2023-06-12T10:03:58.7341063Z Need to get 37.9 MB of archives.
2023-06-12T10:03:58.7341980Z After this operation, 5120 B of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-12T10:03:58.7342692Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.58+20.04.1 [37.9 MB]
2023-06-12T10:03:59.5904547Z Fetched 37.9 MB in 0s (79.3 MB/s)
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6538099Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6538861Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6539636Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6540023Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6540916Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6542166Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6542541Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6543252Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6543543Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6543720Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6543894Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.6843961Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.7174392Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.7420502Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.7910608Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.8534221Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.9268643Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-12T10:03:59.9864844Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-12T10:04:00.0558531Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-12T10:04:00.0883297Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-12T10:04:00.0884456Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-12T10:04:00.0884740Z (Reading database ... 231244 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-12T10:04:00.1001114Z Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.58+20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:00.1893362Z Unpacking snapd (2.58+20.04.1) over (2.58+20.04) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:04.4297247Z Setting up snapd (2.58+20.04.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:07.7589769Z snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
2023-06-12T10:04:07.8097862Z snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
2023-06-12T10:04:07.8428952Z Failed to restart snapd.mounts-pre.target: Operation refused, unit snapd.mounts-pre.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
2023-06-12T10:04:07.8432355Z See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.mounts-pre.target' for details.
2023-06-12T10:04:07.9512709Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:08.1029650Z Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:08.1232132Z Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:11.0475305Z line3
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7058248Z okular 23.04.1 from KDE** installed
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7082316Z line4
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7178819Z 
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7179411Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7180824Z 
2023-06-12T10:04:36.7728727Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-12T10:04:37.0000759Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-12T10:04:37.0015556Z Reading state information...
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1968229Z The following additional packages will be installed:
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1970352Z   guile-2.2-libs libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils6 libntlm0
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1974089Z   mailutils-common postfix
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1977641Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1978262Z   mailutils-mh mailutils-doc procmail postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1994357Z   postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb postfix-sqlite sasl2-bin | dovecot-common
2023-06-12T10:04:37.1995202Z   resolvconf postfix-cdb postfix-doc
2023-06-12T10:04:37.2580917Z The following NEW packages will be installed:
2023-06-12T10:04:37.2589341Z   guile-2.2-libs libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils6 libntlm0
2023-06-12T10:04:37.2593812Z   mailutils mailutils-common postfix
2023-06-12T10:04:37.3018697Z 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
2023-06-12T10:04:37.4312901Z Need to get 7457 kB of archives.
2023-06-12T10:04:37.4314276Z After this operation, 55.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-12T10:04:37.4315002Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 guile-2.2-libs amd64 2.2.7+1-4 [4962 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.5436462Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libntlm0 amd64 1.5-2ubuntu0.1 [14.7 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.5566648Z Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgsasl7 amd64 1.8.1-1 [114 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.5720357Z Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libkyotocabinet16v5 amd64 1.2.76-4.2build1 [318 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.5874804Z Get:5 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 mailutils-common all 1:3.7-2.1 [272 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.6095921Z Get:6 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libmailutils6 amd64 1:3.7-2.1 [437 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.6277684Z Get:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 mailutils amd64 1:3.7-2.1 [138 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:37.6432824Z Get:8 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 postfix amd64 3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2 [1201 kB]
2023-06-12T10:04:38.0327463Z Preconfiguring packages ...
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2077442Z Fetched 7457 kB in 0s (23.0 MB/s)
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2400559Z Selecting previously unselected package guile-2.2-libs:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2479684Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2480253Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2481174Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2481428Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2481608Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2481782Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2483803Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2484236Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2485065Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2485485Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2486584Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2531855Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2583036Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2611631Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2763062Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.2930945Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3168233Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3335386Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3635851Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3669039Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3669529Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3670895Z (Reading database ... 231244 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3768722Z Preparing to unpack .../0-guile-2.2-libs_2.2.7+1-4_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:38.3848654Z Unpacking guile-2.2-libs:amd64 (2.2.7+1-4) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:38.9511654Z Selecting previously unselected package libntlm0:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:04:38.9725995Z Preparing to unpack .../1-libntlm0_1.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:38.9740865Z Unpacking libntlm0:amd64 (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.0432835Z Selecting previously unselected package libgsasl7:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.0626697Z Preparing to unpack .../2-libgsasl7_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.0632733Z Unpacking libgsasl7:amd64 (1.8.1-1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.2912860Z Selecting previously unselected package libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.3116058Z Preparing to unpack .../3-libkyotocabinet16v5_1.2.76-4.2build1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.3128673Z Unpacking libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64 (1.2.76-4.2build1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.3711516Z Selecting previously unselected package mailutils-common.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.3910405Z Preparing to unpack .../4-mailutils-common_1%3a3.7-2.1_all.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.3925751Z Unpacking mailutils-common (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.4472466Z Selecting previously unselected package libmailutils6:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.4675490Z Preparing to unpack .../5-libmailutils6_1%3a3.7-2.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.4691889Z Unpacking libmailutils6:amd64 (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.5392291Z Selecting previously unselected package mailutils.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.5598654Z Preparing to unpack .../6-mailutils_1%3a3.7-2.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.5616378Z Unpacking mailutils (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.6192570Z Selecting previously unselected package postfix.
2023-06-12T10:04:39.6371906Z Preparing to unpack .../7-postfix_3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:04:39.9346734Z Unpacking postfix (3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.0938004Z Setting up libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64 (1.2.76-4.2build1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.0974578Z Setting up libntlm0:amd64 (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.1006918Z Setting up mailutils-common (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.1037076Z Setting up postfix (3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.4929377Z Adding group `postfix' (GID 128) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.5222947Z Done.
2023-06-12T10:04:40.5598903Z Adding system user `postfix' (UID 119) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.5599833Z Adding new user `postfix' (UID 119) with group `postfix' ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.8929605Z Not creating home directory `/var/spool/postfix'.
2023-06-12T10:04:40.9269246Z Creating /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
2023-06-12T10:04:40.9774330Z Adding group `postdrop' (GID 129) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:40.9869150Z Done.
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6196376Z setting myhostname: fv-az196-427.fsmmeu0u0awerkbajh504c0zwb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6243761Z setting alias maps
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6290490Z setting alias database
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6366271Z changing /etc/mailname to fv-az196-427.fsmmeu0u0awerkbajh504c0zwb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6368334Z setting myorigin
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6417713Z setting destinations: $myhostname, fv-az196-427.fsmmeu0u0awerkbajh504c0zwb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net, localhost.fsmmeu0u0awerkbajh504c0zwb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net, , localhost
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6465214Z setting relayhost: 
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6514579Z setting mynetworks: 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6577233Z setting mailbox_size_limit: 0
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6625514Z setting recipient_delimiter: +
2023-06-12T10:04:42.6671146Z setting inet_interfaces: all
2023-06-12T10:04:44.4790092Z setting inet_protocols: all
2023-06-12T10:04:44.4845523Z /etc/aliases does not exist, creating it.
2023-06-12T10:04:44.4914512Z WARNING: /etc/aliases exists, but does not have a root alias.
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5770767Z 
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5773779Z Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with a default configuration.  If you need to 
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5774301Z make changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view 
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5775345Z Postfix configuration values, see postconf(1).
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5775639Z 
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5776324Z After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.
2023-06-12T10:04:44.5776607Z 
2023-06-12T10:04:46.3920111Z Running newaliases
2023-06-12T10:04:46.7295293Z Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service → /lib/systemd/system/postfix.service.
2023-06-12T10:04:49.2956562Z Setting up guile-2.2-libs:amd64 (2.2.7+1-4) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.2999183Z Setting up libgsasl7:amd64 (1.8.1-1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3032060Z Setting up libmailutils6:amd64 (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3064408Z Setting up mailutils (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3152308Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/frm.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/frm (frm) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3220104Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/from.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/from (from) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3286334Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/messages.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/messages (messages) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3352820Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/movemail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/movemail (movemail) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3418371Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/readmsg.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/readmsg (readmsg) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3484626Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/dotlock.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/dotlock (dotlock) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3557161Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/mailx (mailx) in auto mode
2023-06-12T10:04:49.3593807Z Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.6626786Z Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:49.9063089Z Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.21) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:50.2002572Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-12T10:04:56.4482069Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:03.5962287Z line5
2023-06-12T10:05:03.6067717Z 
2023-06-12T10:05:03.6070529Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-12T10:05:03.6070919Z 
2023-06-12T10:05:03.6623356Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-12T10:05:03.8868079Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-12T10:05:03.8883028Z Reading state information...
2023-06-12T10:05:04.0992536Z The following additional packages will be installed:
2023-06-12T10:05:04.0995988Z   libtokyocabinet9
2023-06-12T10:05:04.1005446Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-12T10:05:04.1006010Z   urlview aspell | ispell mixmaster
2023-06-12T10:05:04.1521708Z The following NEW packages will be installed:
2023-06-12T10:05:04.1525971Z   libtokyocabinet9 mutt
2023-06-12T10:05:04.1929062Z 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
2023-06-12T10:05:04.2541887Z Need to get 1304 kB of archives.
2023-06-12T10:05:04.2542477Z After this operation, 5283 kB of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-12T10:05:04.2543127Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libtokyocabinet9 amd64 1.4.48-12 [359 kB]
2023-06-12T10:05:04.2823416Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mutt amd64 1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5 [945 kB]
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7278752Z Fetched 1304 kB in 0s (17.6 MB/s)
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7589856Z Selecting previously unselected package libtokyocabinet9:amd64.
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7664818Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7665299Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7665960Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7666230Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7667632Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7668148Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7668734Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7668929Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7669155Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7669870Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7670046Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7700616Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7758454Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7784259Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.7929718Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8021696Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8330904Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8476713Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8738789Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8774138Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8774360Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8774588Z (Reading database ... 232279 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8873587Z Preparing to unpack .../libtokyocabinet9_1.4.48-12_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:05:04.8900850Z Unpacking libtokyocabinet9:amd64 (1.4.48-12) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:04.9512189Z Selecting previously unselected package mutt.
2023-06-12T10:05:04.9738765Z Preparing to unpack .../mutt_1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-12T10:05:04.9858718Z Unpacking mutt (1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:05.1283062Z Setting up libtokyocabinet9:amd64 (1.4.48-12) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:05.1317544Z Setting up mutt (1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:05.1503490Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:09.8252769Z Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:09.8467979Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5549219Z ##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5562433Z ##[error]
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.


2023-06-12T10:05:12.5563158Z ##[error]

2023-06-12T10:05:12.5563717Z ##[error]WARNING: 
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5564252Z ##[error]apt
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5564774Z ##[error] 
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5565351Z ##[error]does not have a stable CLI interface. 
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5565961Z ##[error]Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-12T10:05:12.5566519Z ##[error]

2023-06-12T10:05:12.5567047Z ##[error]

2023-06-12T10:05:12.5567721Z ##[error]
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.


2023-06-12T10:05:12.5572335Z ##[section]Finishing: Install mail agents
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs, `mailutils` and `mutt` were installed correctly, but your pipeline treats any output to standard error as an error, and `apt` is writing its warning there:

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

To avoid problems, use `apt-get` instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y snapd
#sudo apt-get install -y xpdf
sudo snap install okular
sudo apt-get install -y mailutils
sudo apt-get install -y mutt
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. Addionally I also unchecked the Fail on Standard Error checkbox from the pipeline task.